# Array Cannot Find Symbol-Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am still new to coding but I get a cannot find symbol
I don't know much about arrays but I have been looking on the internet but I cannot find why

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alphabet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] alpha = new String[26];
        alpha[0] = a;

        System.out.println("PLease enter a number from 0-25:");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change a to "a"; in your program.

Comment: @twntee Even your correction wouldn't help.

Comment: Do you mean `alpha[0] = "a";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generally Cannot find symbol error occurs when compiler not able to resolve the symbol.*
Here `a` can not be resolved by the compiler in your code at line

```
 alpha[0]= a;
```

So you are getting error.
Declare it like this

```
String a = "hello";
alpha[0] = a;
```

or

```
alpha[0] = "a";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alpha[0] = a;
```

Variable `a` is not declared, that's why you are getting the error.